# Load data from sqlite database to Redshift using Airflow

Tags: python, sqlite, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am very new to data pipelining. I managed to set up Airflow and connect a sqlite databse through the Airflow UI-Connections Tab. I want to create a simple workflow with the following tasks:

Create a dumb of sqlite db >> Load data in Redshift Cluster.

What is a simple way to connect through a python skript to my sqlite database using airflow and loading it into Redshift? In my opinion it should be a dag with two tasks? Any help?

For now i just have one Dag to execute a python skript *test.py* via BashOperator. The *test.py* just creates a random file to test if the dag works. I don´t have any skript to extract the data from the db and load it into redshift. If it is easier I could switch my source db from sqlite to postgres etc. since my solution is just for a demo case to show how airflow can help to manage moving data from a source db (can even be a .csv) to redshift. Maybe there are easier ways to show the flow of the data with a different source?

```
import airflow
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
        'owner': 'NiHo',
        'start_date': datetime(2015, 8, 1),
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'email': ['random@gmail.com'],
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email_on_retry': True,
        'retries': 1,
}

dag = DAG('simple', default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='testairflow',
        bash_command='python /Users/Niklas/Flow/airflow_home/dags/skripts/test.py',
        dag=dag
    )
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and what you've tried?

Comment: I edited my post above with the code i have unitl now. I just have to build an example workflow from any source of my choice and load some data into redshift.